# how can I shadow the .el files from the Emacs directory with the ones I specify in my init file

Tags: emacs, cedet

So list-load-path-shadows tells which .el files shadow other files. Most of the times the native files found in my emacs distribution shadow newer files I downloaded which I preload in my init file.

For example I have cloned the cedet repository and have that always up to date but the cedet files inside my Emacs 23.4 shadow the newer cedet files i load in my init file.

I can't clone cedet over the directory in /lisp/cedet since packages like eieio or speedbar would still not get overwritten since they are in a different folder.
The temporary solution now is to delete the older packages that came bundled with emacs in order to give priority over the ones I load via my init file.

Is there a way to prioritize the load of my init file over the load of the default emacs packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use CEDET 1.0 or 1.1, the basic install instructions work fine, since many names are different.  If you use CEDET from bzr trunk which uses the new naming scheme, you need to use:

```
(load-file "/home/user/cedet/cedet-devel-load.el")
```

which will perform the necessary magic to remove the built-in CEDET from the load path, and install the new CEDET onto your load path.

See the INSTALL file in CEDET bzr trunk for more.

Comment: I guess this is the only long term solution. Before I used to manually remove the bundled CEDET from emacs and would load the full one when a cc-mode file was open. However this caused some other messed up things to happen

Answer (score 1):

Put the cedet repository directory at the front of your `load-path` and Emacs will pick it up from the cedet area...

Comment: so right now my load-path adds all subdirs of .emacs.d like this
(progn (cd "~/.emacs.d/")(normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
and cedet is under ~/.emacs.d/plugins/cedet and I load it only when cc-mode is triggered because it takes a couple of seconds to load (although byte-compiled) and I don't need at all times. However, when needed I would prefer it to shadow the native Emacs-bundled cedet